# How to manage/disable home button on Android 4.0?

Tags: android, back-button, launcher, home-button

The application that I'm developing must look like a launcher. I opened this topic because of I couldn't find the correct answer in whole topics that I looked at in Stack Overflow.
I want the application to disable or control whole buttons to exit this application. I disabled home and back button on Android 2.3 but it doesn't work on Android 4.0 (except for back button).
To conclude, I couldn't and I want to disable only home button on Android 4.0
Can you give an advice except the other answers?

Comment: If it `needs being a launcher`, then develop a launcher.

Comment: I edited it: `look like a launcher`. I just want to control the two buttons. I can control back button, so I just wanna manage home button.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23349558/2540947 ! 
Hope this will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. This is for security reasons, so that malicious apps cannot take over your device by overriding all the buttons that can exit. The home button is the one sure shot way to be able to leave any app.

In short, no it's not possible, and even if it were, it is a serious disruption in what a user expects out of an app's behavior. You will have to go with making your app into a launcher if you want to achieve this.

Comment: I see. Actually, a few days ago, I saw a kids tablet that was made in China. The feature of tablet was parent control. When tablet opened, an application started as full screen and you can not exit this application without entering password. That's why, I didn't except this reason firstly. But now, I thought about it; the tablet's physic was customized. They put just a circle button (like iPad), and the function was only to act like 'back' button. Now, I see your point. Because of that reason they removed home button and they made their application full screen (even task bar) Thank you so much