# Intercepting home button on Android

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I've researched this a lot and it seems that after ICS normal applications can no longer intercept the Home Button.

However, I see apps like Go Locker that are able to trap the Home Button.

If Go Locker isn't intercepting the home button, what are they doing to prevent the user from going to the home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot intercept the home button. You cannot disable it. The way how the go locker does it is by drawing its layout over other apps. It requires extra permission. See this link for more details [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android)

Comment: @BrienKing if it helps then and you think that its correct then accept my answer