# Android: handle home menu item

Tags: android

**Context:** Very familiar with iOS development and Java. New to Android.

**Problem:** I added a handler to navigate 'back' when the home button is pressed. It works fine, until I add another handler when the user scan button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) //The ID here is no longer R.id.home
    {
        navigateBack();
        return true;
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.scan_button)
    {
        presentScanner();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

As soon as I add the code for the Scan the id is no longer R.id.home. It works if I do this:

```
    if (item.getItemId() == 16908332)
    { . . etc. . .
```

What has happened? How can I correctly get the ID of the home button in this current activity?

**Update:** Changed from R.id.home to 'android.R.id.home' and this works. Why?

Comment: try -> android.R.id.home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pre @Romain Guy the man behind android this cannot be done [see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/trRI99-HszQ). But for older devices you might want to try the [keyevent method.](http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com/). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android) explores additional ways to achieve what you are looking for.

**UPDATE**
android.R.id.home is used in the actionbar to know that your actionappIcon is pressed(left side). While R.id.home is the reference to physical home button(or touch as in nexus 5). Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) for further explanation and use cases.

Comment: Any chance you could also address the updated question? Is that method ok?