# Can't disable home button with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android, homescreen, android-homebutton

I want to keep my activity on the user's screen when the home button is pressed.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android), I can do so by using "TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT".

But I keep going to homescreen on home button click...

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I understand you reaction, but my activity can easily be finished with a button, so the user can go to the homescreen. Thanks for your opinion though

Comment: Just to tell, Facebook Messenger and MX Player also use this method. Don't see many people flushing those apps down their toilet :)

Comment: it's one thing to hide the home button while your app is fullscreen. that's expected behavior. but outright disabling it, nope... not a good idea.

Comment: My app adds users to phone, and this activity starts when the phone gets turned on. Its the activity where you choose the user (+ type in password). I would like to be sure a user gets selected, that's why I want to implement this method. So I guess the user should be expecting this behaviour of such an app.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your use case you need to run a service(runs on bootup) which listens for app launches and which brings up login screen for the user if the he has not logged in so far..refer-[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched) for how to do it.I have seen this approach in many market apps.

Answer (score 0):

TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR is what you need :)