# How to disable hardware buttons in android?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-keypad

I'm building application for blind people to use android devices. For that I want to **disable hardware buttons without power button**. I tried to do that with code

```
      @Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return false;
         }
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            return false;
           }
           if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
             return false;
           }
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                  return false;
             }
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SETTINGS) {
            return false;
          }

           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }
```

I'm using android Kitkat.please try to answer for this without adding negative for this question.thank you.

Comment: hey it is not possible to disable hardware button  in android, you can only override them.

Comment: thanks nikk can I @override them not to read any input or to do any other action for that button click.eg: play a sound, show a pop up menu.

Comment: @SamiraJayasingha: check Answers for this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Comment: Again same question here, you cant prevent them(hardware buttons) to do there default functionality.

Comment: @Chirag I have disable the back button i want to disable other two buttons as well.

Comment: @nikk thanks I got idea from you.