# How to disable android home key 5.1.1

Tags: android

I have developed an android application. It has 3 activities, upon reaching the third activity, I need to disable "back", "home", "task" buttons. I have already done this for "back" and "task" buttons. But I couldn't handle the "home" button disabling. Please help me out of this.

Comment: You cant disable home button for security reason android is not allowing to do that

Comment: thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in lolipop but pre kitkat support [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945431/3514144)

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```