# Disable Home Button in Android (NEC UT880 device) running on Android 4.2.2 version

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am making one lock application and for that I need to disable home button. I already tried all the common solutions available and it works for other android versions but for this device which is running on Android 4.2.2 it fails always.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the home button as it can cause security issues promoting malicious apps etc.

What you can do is add an overlay to your app instead that will cover over other apps.

See this link for more info:[How to disable Home and other system buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make application as launcher.
2. First time when home button is pressed, device ask for choose launcher, select your applicaiton with always options.
3. From the next time when application is opened and you press the home button app never go in background.