# Accessibility Service - Disable home button action android

Tags: android, android-homebutton, accessibilityservice

I want to disable home button action using the accessibility service. I already read the docs from [https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service](http://Accessibility%20Service)

but didn't understand how to do it? Can anyone help me out in this

Comment: What have you tried? What was the problem?

Comment: @Sander I am newbie with this, don't know from where should I start

Answer (score 2):

Create your own Accessibility Service using any tutorial and put this code inside it....

```
public class button_lock extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {

}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}
@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        return true;
    else
       return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}}
```

Then enjoy....

Comment: This only worked for the me on a device with physical touch buttons. When tried with another device with only navigation bar, didn't work.

Comment: Can you share also the xml config file for the upper code? Without it, it does not work at all, even any key is not received

Comment: @CesarMauri sorry to say but this code works for only physical buttons

Answer (score -1):

> Override the below method in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

> And now handle the key event like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
     Log.i("Home Button","Clicked");
    }
   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
   {
        finish();
   }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'TYPE_KEYGUARD', should I use 'TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG' in place of this?

Comment: For Api above 14 use @AndroidGuy

Comment: You can also refer this https://abhik1987.wordpress.com/tag/android-disable-home-button/

Comment: ok let me give a try and one more thing I don't want o jump to main screen on clicking the home button. What should I do in  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
     Log.i("Home Button","Clicked");
    }

Comment: Don't add anything inside that condition. @AndriodGuy

Comment: Getting this error

E/WindowManager: Window : Window{a70c6e9 u0 com.lockscreen.maroof/com.lockscreen.maroof.LockActivity}changes the window type!!
    Original type : 1
    Changed type : 2009
    Window Session Crash
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174643/discussion-between-urvi-joshi-and-android-guy).

Comment: The subject of the question is: AccesibilityService, not an Activity

Comment: What should we declare on xml config for accservice?

Answer (score -1):

You can Disable Home Key by adding this code in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

However, this doesn't work while dialog is showing. To get rid of this problem simply add my code to your Dialog object:

[Disable home Key while Dialog showing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55323243/9751617)

Comment: The question is about accessibility service not Activities