# How to disable bottom navigation view in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to disable my bottom navigation view in my activity but it didn't work. But when i try to hide it and show it, its worked fine. But to disable and enable it, it doesn't work. Btw I used android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

This is the code i tried

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavView = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavView.Enable = true;
```

its not working and i don't know why :/

Comment: When you say disable, what actually are you trying to disable? The individual  navigation items? The shift mode? ...?

Comment: The bottom navigation button or the individual navigation item.

Comment: You can take reference from the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using NavigationView but I saw the same methods on BottomNavigationView (I declared it on my code). To disable the item you can do this:

```
navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);//My navigationview
IMenuItem asd = (IMenuItem)navigationView.Menu.GetItem(2);
asd.SetEnabled(false);
```

If you want to remove items you can do this:

```
navigationView.Menu.RemoveItem(Resource.Id.nav_Cambiar_TPK);
navigationView.Menu.RemoveItem(Resource.Id.nav_nuevo);
```